# Search file for text starting and ending with..and add the inbetween in an array (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I need to parse a lot of files and get their header declaration from all of them and add them all to an array..It doesnt matter if its the same or not since i'll use array_unique after to get only the unique once. 
Some files have comments on the top so i can just pick the first line. The declaration is like this:

```
private ["_aaaaaaa", "_bbbbbb", "_ccccc", "_dddddddd"];
```

but sometimes it can be like this (no space)

```
private["_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_ccccc","_dddddddd"];
```

or like this (if the guy who wrote it didnt pay attention)

```
private["_aaaaaaa", "_bbbbbb","_ccccc", "_dddddddd"];
```

So far i got this:

```
<?php
$str = 'private ["_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_ccccc","_dddddddd"];';
$arr = Array();
$start = 'private [';
$end = '];';

$pattern = sprintf(
    '/%s(.+?)%s/ims',
    preg_quote($start, '/'), preg_quote($end, '/')
);

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    list(, $match) = $matches;
    echo $match;
}
?>
```

which outputs :

```
"_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_ccccc","_dddddddd"
```

Still though that doesnt cover it....plus how will i make that to an array...?
Is there a simple way of doing this ? I've got the function that parses all the files in a folder and subfolder...i just need first to parse all the files and make this array which i'll later use in my main function.
Any help would be appreciated.
-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
/*
    Function-> get_header()
    Input   -> The header string.
    Output  -> An array of header's parameters.
*/
function get_header($string){
    if(preg_match("/private\s?\[(.*?)\];/", $string, $matches)){
        return preg_split("/(\s*)?,(\s*)?/",$matches[1]);
    }
    return Array();
}

//Assuming these to be the different file headers.
$headers = Array(
    'private ["_aaaaaaa", "_bbbbbb", "_ccccc","_dddddddd"];',
    'private ["_4","_3","_2","_1" ];',
    'private["_a", "_b","_c", "_d"];'
);
$header_arr = Array();
foreach($headers as $h){
    $header_arr = array_merge($header_arr, get_header($h));
}
var_dump($header_arr);
```

OUTPUT-

```
/*
    array
      0 => string '"_aaaaaaa"' (length=10)
      1 => string '"_bbbbbb"' (length=9)
      2 => string '"_ccccc"' (length=8)
      3 => string '"_dddddddd"' (length=11)
      4 => string '"_4"' (length=4)
      5 => string '"_3"' (length=4)
      6 => string '"_2"' (length=4)
      7 => string '"_1" ' (length=5)
      8 => string '"_a"' (length=4)
      9 => string '"_b"' (length=4)
      10 => string '"_c"' (length=4)
      11 => string '"_d"' (length=4)
*/
```

Comment: awesome! From there on i can add them all to an array easily.
But how could i use your preg_match to match the headers while i open the files?
Thats my biggest problem...I can file() read each line...but using that pregmatch to grab the private is the tricky part